# Avoid entering text search vim command history

Tags: vim

I often use search and replace commands using / in vim scripts and user commands. One anoying side effect is that the search appears in the search command history when typing / followed by cursor-up. Can I prevent vim to enter the searches within scripts into the history? Also: Is there a better way to remove highlighting after such a search within a script or user command than to search for a very unlikely expression like /I_DO_NOT_EXIST_IN_THIS_FILE?

Answer (score 4):

Type `:noh` to cancel the highlighting.

Type `:call search('I_DO_NOT_EXIST_IN_THIS_FILE')` to search without search-history.

You can also `:call histdel('/', -1)` to delete latest entry in search history.

Comment: What about inverse search with ?

Comment: Type `:help search()` to read more. There's a flags argument.

Comment: With :call search('mysearch','b'), I see. But now I have expressions like ':?\(^[ \t]\+.*\)\@<!\n?,/\(^[ \t]\+.*\)\@<!\n/-1' to select ranges (to pass to ! for example) how would I accomplish this with search?

Answer (score 2):

I use F9 to turn off/on highlighting on the previous search:

```
" Highlight searches 
set hlsearch
noremap <F9> :set hlsearch! hlsearch?<CR>
```